# How to get a variable of type char to have a value of ' in c#

Tags: c#

A bit of a dumb one... but how do I get a variable of type char to have a value of `'`?

e. g.

```
char c = ''';
char a = 'A';
char b = 'B';
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
char c = '\'';
```

the backslash is called an escape character.

and if you want a backslash it's

```
char c = '\\';
```

Here's some more for good measure:

- \t - tab
- \n - new line
- \uXXXX - where XXXX is the hexadecimal value of a unicode character

Comment: Slash is /, the character \ is called backslash.

Answer (score 2):

> char a=65 means 'A' in c++. don't know whether it will work in c#

To complete you answer:
in C#, the following statement won't compile, because you're trying to put an Int32 into a Char (no implicit casting exists)

```
char a = 65;
```

To convert ASCII codes to a character, you have to use the static Convert class in C#:

```
char a = Convert.ToChar(65);  // where 65 is the ascii
```

Comment: Though no *implicit conversion* exists from int to char, an explicit conversion does exist, and therefore you can use the cast operator. char a = (char)65; is legal.